# How to restart apache2 when I get a pid conflict and php not processed by the server

Tags: linux, apache, vagrant

There are processes named 'apache2' running which do not match y our pid file which are left untouched in the name of safety, Please review the s ituation by hand.
Following Test Were Done

```
no of pids -> sudo pidof apache2
3501 3500 3498 3497
Remove 3497 id and sudo service apache2 start - >
Error:  
 * Starting web server apache2                                                    *
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
```

Output of config test was:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_default.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

The Apache error log may have more information.

Need your assist ....

even php not processed in the server

Comment: I disable sudo a2dismod authz_default.load still errors comes

Answer (score 0):

php 5.5 not compatible with precise64 version..so I tried with trusty64 all work fine..